$\sigma$ - Algebra of Symmetric Differences
Recently I've been solving some exercises in Fremlin's Measure Theory and came upon this (I'm slightly paraphasing)

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal{I}$ be a $\sigma$ - ideal
on $\Omega$. Show that
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_1 = \{ E \Delta A \;  | \; E \in \mathcal{F} \; \text{and} \; A \in \mathcal{I} \}
\end{equation}
is a $\sigma$ - algebra on $\Omega$.

I've proved that $\Omega \in \Sigma_1$ and that $\Sigma_1$ is closed under complements, but I had my fair share of problems showing that $\Sigma_1$ is closed under countable unions. Can anyone help with this?
Definition: Let $\Omega$ be a set. A set $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is called a $\sigma$ - ideal of $\Omega$ if

$\emptyset \in \mathcal{I}$.

$\forall A, B \in \mathcal{I}$, if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \in \mathcal{I}$, then $A \in \mathcal{I}$.

If $A_n \in \mathcal{I}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\cup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n \in \mathcal{I}$.




Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal{I}$ be a $\sigma$ - ideal
on $\Omega$. Let
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_1 = \{ E \Delta A \;  | \; E \in \mathcal{F} \; \text{and} \; A \in \mathcal{I} \}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_2 = \{ (E \setminus A) \cup B \;  | \; E \in \mathcal{F}, \; A, B \in \mathcal{I}, \;  A \subseteq E \; \text{and} \; B \cap E=\emptyset\}
\end{equation}
Then $\Sigma_1 =\Sigma_2$.

Proof:
Since $\mathcal{I}$ is $\sigma$-ideal, for all $E \in \mathcal{F} \; \text{and} \; A, B \in \mathcal{I}$, if $A \subseteq E$ and $B \cap E=\emptyset$, we have that $A \cup B \in \mathcal{I}$ and then
$ (E \setminus A) \cup B = E \Delta (A \cup B) \in \Sigma_1 $. So $\Sigma_2 \subseteq \Sigma_1$.
Now, for all $E \in \mathcal{F} \; \text{and} \; A \in \mathcal{I}$, we have that $ E\cap A \subseteq A$ and $A \setminus E \subseteq A$. Since $\mathcal{I}$ is $\sigma$-ideal, we have that
$ E\cap A, A \setminus E \in \mathcal{I}$. So,
$$E \Delta A = (E \setminus (E\cap A) ) \cup (A \setminus E) \in \Sigma_2$$ So $\Sigma_1 \subseteq \Sigma_2$. So $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2$.
$\square$
Now it is easy to see that:

$\Omega \in \Sigma_2$
$\Sigma_2$ is closed under set difference.
$\Sigma_2$ is closed under countable disjoint unions

So $\Sigma_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. So $\Sigma_1$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Thanks for the great response, that was a great proof! Do you have a reference for this result?

@GiordanoRibeiro ,  This result is appears as exercises in some books. It is also common to find a special case of this result where the $\sigma$-ideal is the collection of all null-sets of a measure.
